# Workflow cancels for everyone but SCA

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, error

I created a workflow in SPD that works fine for me, but seems to cancel for anyone else even if the person has Full Control permissions.

This is the emailed error message: **The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.** From what I have been able to already troubleshoot, this is a pretty generic error. I've checked permissions on the Workflow tasks list. It seems to be a permission issue but I cannot figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting in a LOG HISTORY action into the workflow after each step and learned that it was a permission problem with the child list it was creating an item on. Turns out the person didnt have proper create permissions on the other list. Once I granted permissions, it worked fine.